# Ошибка при увеличении сайта

Tags: html, css

При увеличении сайта появляются повторение заднего фона

[image: Ошибка на краях]

Вот css код что отвечает за фон

```css
body
{
    background: linear-gradient(to left top, rgb(0, 184, 212, 0.9), rgb(29, 233, 182, 0.9)), url(../img/Color_Fill_1.png) 0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
    max-height: 750px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Кто знает как убрать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас задний фон повторяется. Чтобы такое не случилось пишите:

```cs
body
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```